# addressing issues with my basic python Speed ticketing program

Tags: python-3.x

Hi so  I just started learning python at school but haven't understood the teachers teachings and I have started my code bu t run into multiple errors, the program is about someone talking to an online speed ticketing system, it asks how much over the speed limit the person is going and gives the appropriate fines. I am getting errors such as If the person is at the sped limit the code should stop if hes over the code should carry on, and I cnt figure out how when he inputs letters asks fo the question again, This is my second time using stack overflow please dont downgrade for the way I set out the question

```
fine = []

"""the check_warrant function uses for loop to
check the list if it matches with the drivers' name"""

def check_warrant(name):
    for person in warrant:
        if person == name:
            print(person.upper(), "IS WANTED FOR ARREST!!!")


def enterFine():
    individual_fine = 0
    validInput = False
    while validInput == False:
        try:
            speedlimit = int(input("Enter speedlimit :"))#local variables
            if speedlimit >= 0:
                speed = int(input("Enter speed :"))
            amountOver = speed - speedlimit


            if amountOver > 0:
                validInput = True
                print("You are over the speed limit")
                individual_fine += 630

            else:
                print("You are driving under the speed limit")
                return 0
        except ValueError:
            print("ERROR: Please enter number values only")
    return individual_fine        

#Main Routine
for i in range(1):
    name = input("Enter the name of the driver? :")
check_warrant(name) #calls the check_warrant function and enter the value name
ind_fine = enterFine()
print("Fine for {} is {}".format(name,ind_fine))

#Main routine
moreInput == "Y"
while moreInput == "Y":
    #Ask for input
    name = str(input("Enter name: "))
    enterFine() #enter fine function

    askInput = "X"
    while askInput != "Y" and askInput !="N":
        askInput = input("Do you wish to enter another speeder (Y/N): ")

    if askInput == "N":
        moreInput = "N"
```

Comment: Calling `check_warrant(name)` twice?

Comment: `lens(fines)` is illegal and undefined.

Comment: @DirtyBit I have removed one of them now

Comment: `totalFines` not defined, should be `total_fines`

Comment: @DirtyBit thnaks, How about when the user inputs letters?

Comment: You are not using the `fine` list anywhere

Comment: @DirtyBit I am carrying on the code they will be used later on

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Continuing from the comments in the quesiton:

**OP**:

> I am getting errors such as If the person is at the sped limit the code should stop if hes over the code should carry on, and I cnt figure out how when he inputs letters asks fo the question again

**Ans**:

You need a `except ValueError:` to catch the invalid types. Also, I have fixed a few other bumps.

```
warrant = ["Helga Norman", "James Wilson", "Zachary Conroy"]
fine = []

"""the check_warrant function uses for loop to
check the list if it matches with the drivers' name"""

def check_warrant(name):
    for person in warrant:
        if person == name:
            print(person.upper(), "IS WANTED FOR ARREST!!!")


def enterFine():
    individual_fine = 0
    validInput = False
    while validInput == False:
        try:
            speedlimit = int(input("Enter speedlimit :"))#local variables
            if speedlimit >= 0:
                speed = int(input("Enter speed :"))
            amountOver = speed - speedlimit


            if amountOver > 0:
                validInput = True
                print("You are over the speed limit")
                individual_fine += 630

            else:
                print("You are driving under the speed limit")
                return 0
        except ValueError:
            print("ERROR: Please enter number values only")
    return individual_fine        

#Main Routine
for i in range(3):
    name = input("Enter the name of the driver? :")
    check_warrant(name) #calls the check_warrant function and enter the value name
    ind_fine = enterFine()
    print("Fine for {} is {}".format(name,ind_fine))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Enter the name of the driver? : DirtyBit
Enter speedlimit :What?
ERROR: Please enter number values only
Enter speedlimit :Oh
ERROR: Please enter number values only
Enter speedlimit :120
Enter speed :115
You are driving under the speed limit
```

Comment: Hi i aded a section after which asks for another driver but it say I have not defined "moreInput" but I have ```#Main routine
moreInput == "Y"
while moreInput == "Y":
    #Ask for input
    name = str(input("Enter name: "))
    enterFine() #enter fine function
    
    askInput = "X"
    while askInput != "Y" and askInput !="N":
        askInput = input("Do you wish to enter another speeder (Y/N): ")
        
    if askInput == "N":
        moreInput = "N"```

Comment: @roobo I have added a loop to get more drivers fine, is that what you want?

Comment: I got a trace back error on line 38, yeah I want the program to ask for another driver

Comment: @roobo What error are you getting?

Comment: I fixed the traceback but now it is asking the drivers name three times at the start

Comment: @roobo Make sure the code is properly indented.

Comment: when ```name = input("Enter the name of the driver? :")``` is indented it works but ask the question three times, when it is dedented it gives a traceback error

Comment: @roobo copy-paste the above answer and run it?

Comment: I did copy paste i get this error, name = input("Enter the name of the driver? :")
builtins.IndentationError: expected an indented block (x-wingide-python-shell://106508040/2, line 38)

Comment: I fixed it, I indented it and change the range to 1 so it asks once I think you got mixed up wiht the bnext step, This code ```#Main routine moreInput == "Y" while moreInput == "Y": #Ask for input name = str(input("Enter name: ")) enterFine() #enter fine function askInput = "X" while askInput != "Y" and askInput !="N": askInput = input("Do you wish to enter another speeder (Y/N): ") if askInput == "N": moreInput = "N"``` is meant to ask for a new driver after the first one is completed but am also getting errors in this one

Comment: @roobo That was not a part of your original code so I would not know about it. If this fixed, you may either edit your question to add the newer part you're stuck at or ask another question if it differs.

Comment: so what was the in range of (3) meant to do? and ill ad second bit now

Comment: To iterate the loop 3 times.

Comment: and btw how do i edit original post?

Comment: Hi i marked it can you just help me with one last thing the last art of the code? I know you probably have other obligation

Comment: @roobo Please go ahead.